# For-each. Accessing array items by key name: "Illegal string offset"

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$leggi = Array("LeggeRegionale" =>  
    Array("0" =>
        Array("intestazione" => "Legge regionale...", "articolato" => 
            Array("articolo" => 
                Array("num_articolo" => "Art. 25", "rubrica" => "Abrogazione", "commi" => 
                    Array("num_comma" => "1.", "alinea" => "", "corpo" => "L'articolo..."),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

With the following code I can loop through the array `[LeggeRegionale]` and all its sub-arrays as wanted.

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($leggi);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
    foreach ($leggi[LeggeRegionale] as $legge) {
        echo $legge['intestazione'].PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($legge[articolato] as $key => $articolo) {
            echo $articolo['num_articolo'];
            echo $articolo['rubrica'].PHP_EOL;
            foreach($articolo[commi] as $value) {
                echo $value['num_comma'];    // <--- Doesn't work. Illegal string offset
                if (!is_array($value)) {     // <--- Does work.
                    echo $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
echo "</pre>";
```

As I need to do some string operations on the items of the arrays, I need to access to each item using its key.

I understand that "illegal string offset" means that the item is a string and infact the `IF (!is_array)` statement below the error demonstrate that.

What I absolutely don't understand is: but `[commi]` isn'it an array as `[LeggeRegionale]` and `[articolo]` where I can print an item by simply write for example `$articolo['num_articolo']`?

**What's the difference between the array `[articolo]` and the array `[commi]`??**

`VAR_DUMP` says:

```
array(1) {
    ["LeggeRegionale"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>
                array(2) {
                    ["intestazione"]=>
                        string(18) "Legge regionale..."
                    ["articolato"]=>
                        array(1) {
                            ["articolo"]=>
                                array(3) {
                                    ["num_articolo"]=>
                                        string(7) "Art. 25"
                                    ["rubrica"]=>
                                        string(11) "Abrogazione"
                                    ["commi"]=>
                                        array(3) {
                                            ["num_comma"]=>
                                                string(2) "1."
                                            ["alinea"]=>
                                                string(0) ""
                                            ["corpo"]=>
                                                string(13) "L'articolo..."
                                    }
                               }
                          }
                     }
                }
           }
```

**Summing up I would like to access the items of the array `[commi]` like this:**

```
echo $value['num_comma'];
echo $value['alinea'];
echo $value['corpo'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping the last array just use it as

```
foreach ($leggi['LeggeRegionale'] as $legge) {
    echo $legge['intestazione'];
    foreach ($legge['articolato'] as $key => $articolo) {
        echo $articolo['num_articolo'];
        echo $articolo['rubrica'];
        if (is_array($articolo['commi'])) {
            echo $articolo['commi']['num_comma'];
            echo $articolo['commi']['alinea'];
            echo $articolo['commi']['corpo'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As said (and as you may see from my code) I know I can access values using `$value`, but as asked I would like to access them using `$value['num_comma'];`.

Comment: `echo $articolo['commi']['num_comma'];` loops 4 times `num_comma` and it outputs: `1.1.1.1.`

Comment: Ok, in your "pastebin" it works because you removed the last `for-each`. You should now correct your answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is something wrong with your array structure, try var_dump() to see if it is correct.

Comment: Seems to be comment more

Comment: The array structure is correct. Proof is the `print_r` I added.